# how to fit multiple containers in a parent container

Tags: html, css

I had a container, what I was trying to add was more containers nested inside the main parent container but after adding the containers and added some style to them they won't fit inside the parent container. I set my height and width for the nested container to be 100% but the height exceeds the scope of the parent container and I can't figure out why. How do I make a nested container fit a parent container full(100% both width and height)? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiperCon1', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 2,
  spaceBetween: 5,
  scrollbar: {
    el: 'Scroll1',
    hide: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    invert: false,
    forceToAxis: true,
  },
});
```

```css
.con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 85%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-top-left-radius: 0%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0%;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0%;
}

.row-con {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-con-1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.col-con-2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.col-con-3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.swiperCon1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiperWrap1 .swiper-slide {
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="../package/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

  <div class="container border-primary con">
    <div class="row row-con">
      <div class="col col-con-1">
        <div class="swiper-container swiperCon1">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper swiperWrap1">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
          </div>
          <!-- Add Scrollbar -->
          <div class="swiper-scrollbar Scroll1" style="background-color: grey; right: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-con-2">
        two of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col col-con-3">
        three of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe the only issue is that you've neglected to specify a height for your columns, i.e:

```
.col {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Chrome/firefox dev tools are your friend! If you press F12 you can open up the DOM inspector which allows you to view the page's elements - in this case, it was trivial enough to find what was wrong by selecting the column in the inspector and seeing that everything was the correct height except for the columns. [Here's a link to the Chrome dev tools docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overview/). I'm sure you can find something similar for firefox.

Modified snippet is below.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiperCon1', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 2,
  spaceBetween: 5,
  scrollbar: {
    el: 'Scroll1',
    hide: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    invert: false,
    forceToAxis: true,
  },
});
```

```css
.con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 85%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-top-left-radius: 0%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0%;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0%;
}

.row-con {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  height: 100%;
}

.col-con-1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.col-con-2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.col-con-3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.swiperCon1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiperWrap1 .swiper-slide {
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="../package/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

  <div class="container border-primary con">
    <div class="row row-con">
      <div class="col col-con-1">
        <div class="swiper-container swiperCon1">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper swiperWrap1">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
          </div>
          <!-- Add Scrollbar -->
          <div class="swiper-scrollbar Scroll1" style="background-color: grey; right: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-con-2">
        two of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col col-con-3">
        three of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```